# Spring Boot, AOP and exception handler

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, aop

### Context

##### What I'm satisfied with

I'm creating a Spring Boot REST service returning a `ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>`. I also have a @ControllerAdvice for exception handling. It all works fine.

I've been asked to provide logging (endpoints being called, execution time, HTTP status and such). The most solid way I can think of to do it was to use an Aspect. I made one with some `@Around` pointcuts, like below, and that, too, works fine in the nominal case.

```java
@Around(value = "@annotation(requestMapping)", argNames = "pjp,requestMapping")
public Object trackExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, RequestMapping requestMapping) throws Throwable {
    return trackExecutionTime(pjp, requestMapping.method()[0], requestMapping.value()[0]);
}
```

##### What's brittle or broken

My problem now occurs in case of an exception. I couldn't find a better way than injecting my exception handler into my Aspect. It's dirty, brittle, and even completely broken in my case:

```java
// Simplified
private Object trackExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start();

    Object result = null;
    try {
        result = pjp.proceed();
    } catch (MyException1 e) {
        result = exceptionHandler.handleMyException1(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = exceptionHandler.handleException(e, webRequest);
    } finally {
        stopWatch.stop();
        doLog(result, stopWatch.getTotalTimeMillis(),
            ((ResponseEntity) result).getStatus());
    }
    return result;
}
```

- Brittle: new cases in exception handler means new catches to add here. I don't like it.
- Broken: Spring isn't happy, at all. He expects a StreamingResponseBody and I return an ErrorDto. The ExceptionHandling is broken and the endpoint returns Spring's generic error + 500 instead of my DTO + appropriate HTTP status.

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: StreamingResponseBody expected: lu.pgd.dri.bidas.nist.rest.dto.NistRestApiErrorDto
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:517) ~[jakarta.servlet-api-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: StreamingResponseBody expected: lu.pgd.dri.bidas.nist.rest.dto.NistRestApiErrorDto
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.instanceCheckFailed(Assert.java:702) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:602) ~[spring-core-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.handleReturnValue(StreamingResponseBodyReturnValueHandler.java:90) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
    ...
```

I of course did a PoC before starting this aspect, but I used `ResponseEntity<String>` in both success and failure cases, so I missed this issue.

### My questions

- **Real, primary question**: Is there a way to enhance my aspect so that I can achieve my purpose?
- **Bonus question**: Does that enhancement allow me to handle exceptions in a generic way, by throwing it to some kind of Dispatcher in the Spring context, for instance?

As a potential lead, I considered not catching the exception and making the ExceptionHandler call the log service itself, but then I don't know how to get the StopWatch to have the execution time.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Spring Boot already exposes metrics you want, why reinvent the wheel. Or write an eventlistener for the `ServletRequestHandledEvent` and enable event publishing in the `DispatcherServlet`. But I would suggest using the first (the already available metrics) and use the out-of-the-box provided metrics (by including `spring-boot-starter-actuator`).

Comment: Thanks for the input, @M.Deinum. The actuator won't do, because I've been asked to log individual calls to DB, so that stats can be made by controller, by endpoint, potentially months from now. Actuator is too much of a "right now" approach for what I'm asked. The `RequestHandledEvent` might be just what I need, though. Drilling in that direction.

Comment: (My question was also simplified, and I normally have a custom annotations to determine which controllers are concerned with this logging. Will see how I can negociate around this requirement.)

Comment: And why wouldn't the actuator do. If you have enabled tracing from end to end you can do exactly what you want, you can even enrich the tags so you can make that possible. Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Checking it out, thanks. Didn't know that particular feature indeed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: (I'm not one to reinvent the wheel. I'm not even a fan of AOP. Maybe you should just assume, when someone is missing the obvious, that they just don't know the feature exists and be just a bit more didactic. Spring is a vast framework and not many of us have the leisure of learning it all in details. Written communication is quite complicated as many indicators are missing, like tone and body language. As good as your knowledge is, @M.Deinum, you might be mistaken for condescending in your answers. I'm really grateful for the help and pointers, though.)

Comment: IMO, he was not condescending, just clear and assertive. Knowledge and straight talk are not the same as arrogance.

Comment: I hear that, and I only said it was a possible mistake, but too much conciseness leads to loss of information, hence the part of my comment recommending a more didactic approach. :) As I said, I appreciated the advice and pointers, but they were so concise I had trouble getting to the matter of one of them: pointing to Actuator and Actuator's httptrace aren't the same thing, but once I had that element, I could unblock my situation, all thanks to him, and with a better approach than my initial one.

Comment: Probably Marten is right with his approach. Let me just comment on the aspect part, because that is my sweet spot, not Spring: If your aspect is broken and returns the wrong object type, why don't you fix that? And is is not better to add another case to your aspect than to scatter exception handling across the whole code base? At least, there it is all in one place and can be maintained properly.

Comment: I am also wondering if it makes much sense to mix two things: timing/logging and exception handling. Nothing forces you to do that. Just let the aspect do the logging and pass through the exceptions, not handling them there at all. Another aspect, interceptor or whichever appropriate Spring thingy can do that.

Comment: Relevant questions, but you need to know Spring to understand that. :) My aspect is actually short-circuiting some of Spring's mechanics to handle exceptions properly, hence my problems. In a Spring controller, you typically declare the nominal return type. In case of an error, you throw the exception and you have an ExceptionHandler that will build an alternate response from it. That's also the part that'll tell "OK, since I'm in case of an exception, I return another type."

Comment: Properly speaking, I don't wish to make exception handling inside my aspect. On the contrary, I'd like to avoid it if possible. Since I intercept calls to the controller with my `@Around`, Spring's dispatcher loses track and I must admit I don't know it deep enough to find what I could call in the framework to handle it correctly — and I probably shouldn't need to. That's why M. Deinum was indeed probably right: there are things in Spring to handle my case, and I should rely on them. Events and httptrace are two perfect solutions I didn't know about.

Comment: I really do not understand why Spring's dispatcher would lose track because of an aspect, because aspects, unless you annotate your advice with `@Async`, are executed synchronously. Hence, they should be pretty much transparent if you simply pass through all exceptions and let them focus on logging. The exception handler can take care of the rest. I think I know enough Spring to be bold enough to say that.

Comment: BTW, If you really just want to log, you do not need an `@Around` advice at all, probably `@After` (or a pair of `@AfterReturning` and `@AfterThrowing`, if you want to bind the exception to an advice parameter) would suffice and not change the control flow at all.